# Function Overloading Mechanism

Tags: scala

```
class X
class Y extends X
class Z extends Y
class M {
  def f(x: X): String = "f with X at M"
  def f(x: Y): String = "f with Y at M"
}
class N extends M {
  override def f(x: Y): String = "f with Y at N"
  def f(x: Z): String = "f with Z at N"
}

val z: Z = new Z
val y: Y = z
val x: X = y
val m: M = new N
println(m.f(x))
// m dynamically matches as type N and sees x as type X thus goes into class M where it calls "f with X at M"
println(m.f(y))
// m dynamically matches as type N and sees y as type Y where it calls "f with Y at N"
println(m.f(z))
// m dynamically matches as type N and sees z as type Z where it calls "f with Z at N"
```

Consider this code, I don't understand with the final call println(m.f(z)) doesn't behave as I wrote in the comments - is there a good resource for understanding how overloading works in Scala?

Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly overloading in Scala works the same as in Java.

Secondly, it's about static and dynamic binding. Let's find out what compiler see. You have `m: M` object. Class `M` has `f(X)` and `f(Y)` methods. When you call `m.f(z)` compiler resolves that method `f(Y)` should be called because `Z` is subclass of `Y`. It's a very important point: compiler doesn't know real class of `m` object that's why it knows nothing about method `N.f(Z)`. And it's called static binding: compiler resolves **method's signature**. Later, in runtime, dynamic binding happens. JVM knows real class of `m` and it calls `f(Y)` which is overloaded in `Z`. 
Hope my explanations are clearly enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
class x
class Y extends X
class Z extends Y
class M {
  def f(x: X): String = "f with X at M"
  def f(x: Y): String = "f with Y at M"
}
class N extends M {
  override def f(x: Y): String = "f with Y at N"
  def f(x: Z): String = "f with Z at N"
}

val z: Z = new Z
val y: Y = z
val x: X = y
val m: M = new N
println(m.f(x))
// m dynamically matches as type N and sees x as type X thus goes into class M where it calls "f with X at M"
println(m.f(y))
// m dynamically matches as type N and sees y as type Y where it calls "f with Y at N"
println(m.f(z))
// m dynamically matches as type N and sees z as type Z where it calls "f with Z at N"
```

Because the function will be overloaded on N.so N is depends on m.f(y) .finally it is related with x and y that is reason z function will call

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
val m: M = new N
```

It means that m is capable of doing everything that class M can. M has two methods - first which can take X, other Y.

And hence when you do this

```
m.f(z)
```

Runtime is going to search for a method which can accept z (of type Z). The method in N is not a candidate here because of two reasons

1. The reference is of type `M`
2. Your `N` does not *override* any method of `M` which can accept an argument of type `Z`. You *do* have a method in `N` which can accept a `Z` but that's not a candidate because it's not overriding anything from `M`
3. The best match is `f` in `M` which can accept a `Y` this is because `Z` ISA `Y`

You can get what your last comment says if

1. You define a method in `M` which takes argument of type `Z` and then you override it in `N`
2. You instantiate a val of type N e.g: `val m : N = new N`

I think the existing questions on SO already elaborate this point.